# Pre-computing a log and exp table for a primitive polynomial in $GF(2^8)$

Tags: aes, finite-field

I'm new on the topic of finite fields, specifically $GF(2^8)$.

I've come across the information that it's possible to implement multiplication using logarithm and exponential tables. But how are these tables formed exactly? Some answers talk about a generator while others talk about using a primitive polynomial. Are those the same?

What I exactly want to know is how pre-compute the log and exp table using the following primitive polynomial: $$x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + 1$$

Comment: just to clarify , do you mean the Xtime table such as in AES?

Comment: I checked that question before @kelalaka, but they don't use a primitive polynomial to calculate the AES log table, they use a generator. Is it the same? Maybe I'm getting it wrong.

Comment: @Luxzero how do you perform the step `where mul denotes multiplication in the AES field.` without a primitive polynomial?

Comment: @kelalaka That's it! I missed the relevance of that step I guess. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.